# Communication between two netcats

Tags: sockets, netcat

Guys why is this happening:

I launch this on one console `nc -l 5000 -e /bin/bash`
And this on another one on the same pc `nc localhost 5000`
But it shows connection refused!

Why is this happening and how to correct it.

Answer (score 2):

When you want nc to listen, you need to use the `-p` parameter to specify the listening port like this:

```bsh
nc -l -p 5000 -e /bin/bash
```

Comment: Boom it worked !!! U rock!